# Icon appears on simulator but not on my iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, icons

When i run my application on my iphone it doesn't show the icon i want , but the default one. I tried everything but i really don't know how to fix this problem.
The icons are 58x58 , 80x80 , 120x120 , 180x180. What should i do? Thank you in advance.

Here are the screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQLda.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzONE.jpg

Here the  error messages: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpyej.jpg

Comment: Can you show us what those warnings and error messages are saying?

Comment: Here the error messages http://imgur.com/S8xKVX4,1LZLKdH,0mY2aRK

Comment: You can add those images to the question inline by [editing your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26330304/edit).

Comment: Your last screenshot indicates that the image files are either not found or no PNG files? Have you used an Jpeg and just given it the extension `.png`?

Comment: I don't know if it's fixed, but iOS simulator is case insensitive for image names, but device are case sensitive, check that your image names are correct.

Comment: Thank you Klaas.I converted the images from jpg to png and i fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to select target membership for that image.

[image: /Users/Steve/Desktop/target.png]